# Inversion geometry: If P,P' and Q,Q' are any two pairs of inverse points then these four point lie on a circle

Tags: geometry

I have an inversion geometry question:

If P,P' and Q,Q' are any two pairs of inverse points, that do not lie on the same diameter of the circle of inversion,then these four point lie on a circle and
$$\angle OPQ = \angle OQ'P' ~and ~ \angle OQP=\angle OP'Q'$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What is stopping you from progressing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_secants_theorem

Comment: hi Arthur,


I've made sketches. I have $$OP*OP'=OQ * OQ'=r^2 $$
I'm stuck at the beginning.
Proving the angles will be easy with both triangles having the same angle O. But how to prove $$P,Q,P',Q' \in circle$$ ?

Comment: Using $OP\cdot OP'=OQ\cdot OQ'$, one can show that triangles $OPQ$ and $OQ'P'$ are similar by side-angle-side, then $\angle OPQ=\angle OQ'P'$ and $\angle OQP=\angle OP'Q'$, then you can show that sum of opposite angles of quadrilateral  with vertices in P, P', Q, Q' is 180°, then these four points lie on a circle.

Comment: Thank you Ivan!!!